# Bash command not running in Apache CGI Shell

Tags: linux, apache, bash, shell, sed

I have a script that runs when I click a button on the http server on my linux machine.
The file is in cgi-bin and is executable.

But it seems like two lines of this script arent working

```
#!/bin/bash

IPADDR=`echo "$QUERY_STRING" | sed -n 's/^.*IPADDR=\([^&]*\).*$/\1/p' | sed "s/+/ /g"`
SUBNET=`echo "$QUERY_STRING" | sed -n 's/^.*SUBNET=\([^&]*\).*$/\1/p' | sed "s/+/ /g"`
DHCP=`echo "$QUERY_STRING" | sed -n 's/^.*DHCP=\([^&]*\).*$/\1/p' | sed "s/+/ /g"`
```

(2lines that arent working)

```
sed -i.bak "s/IPADDR=.*/IPADDR=$IPADDR/g" test
sed -i.bak "s/NETMASK=.*/NETMASK=$SUBNET/g" test

echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo ""
DHCP=`echo "$QUERY_STRING" | sed -n 's/^.*DHCP=\([^&]*\).*$/\1/p' | sed "s/+/ /g"`
echo "<html><head><title>IP CHANGED</title></head>"
echo "<body>IP changed to: "
echo "$IPADDR <br>"
echo "<body>SUBNET changed to: "
echo "$SUBNET <br>"
echo "DHCP $DHCP"
echo "</body></html>"
```

Contents of file test

```
DEVICE=p32p1
BOOTPROTO=static
DHCPCLASS=
HWADDR=00:01:2e:48:f0:f3
IPADDR=3333333333
NETMASK=4444444444
ONBOOT=yes
```

sed never changes the file.

Also here is my HTML

```
<form action="cgi-bin/IPChange.sh" method="get">
Enter an IP Address: <input type="text" name="IPADDR"></input><br>
Enter a Subnet Mask: <input type="text" name="SUBNET"></input><br>
<input type="radio" name="DHCP" value="on">Enable DHCP
<input type="radio" name="DHCP" value="off">Disable DHCP<br>
<input type="submit" name="subbtn" value="Submit">
<form>
```

Comment: Apache does not have permissions to edit your file. Aside from that, letting bash scripts to run by web process sounds like horrible idea

Comment: Its a simple case that Im trying to implement, How can I give apache permission?

Comment: Instead of increasing apache's permission, you might want to just give the `test` file write permission for all users:  chmod a+x /path/to/test

Comment: BTW:  This script looks like it could be very susceptible to a command line injection attack.  If the user submits a query string like: `"; rm /* -rf; echo "`, they could wipe out your filesystem.

Comment: Changing the write permissions didn't work either

Comment: It could be because of the `i.bak` option, which is causing it to try to create a backup file, and maybe it doesn't have permissions to do so.  In any case, I think you need logic at the beginning of the script to sanitize the input to prevent an injection type of attack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This must be a combination of filesystem permissions and SELinux configuration problem.

The filesystem part is easier to fix. Your web server process probably runs as the `apache` user, so make sure it has the correct permissions to the file you want to rewrite. To confirm the filesystem permissions are ok, temporarily disable SELinux and check if the writing works:

```
echo 0 >/selinux/enforce
```

If this works, then turn SELinux back on:

```
echo 1 >/selinux/enforce
```

and then fix your SELinux settings. Here are some hints for that from [this other answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50639/httpd-cant-write-to-folder-file-because-of-selinux), in particular:

> You must either give the directory structure a context of `httpd_sys_rw_content_t`, or give them a context of `public_content_rw_t` and enable `allow_httpd_anon_write` and/or `allow_httpd_sys_script_anon_write`. See the `httpd_selinux(8)` man page for details.

In addition, I would rewrite your script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
config=/var/www/net.config

while IFS== read name value; do
    case $name in
        IPADDR) IPADDR=$value ;;
        SUBNET) SUBNET=$value ;;
        DHCP) DHCP=$value ;;
    esac
done < <(sed -e 's/&/\n/g' <<< $QUERY_STRING)

is_valid() {
    # todo: validate the input params
    return 1
}

if is_valid; then
    sed -i.bak e "s/IPADDR=.*/IPADDR=$IPADDR/g" -e "s/NETMASK=.*/NETMASK=$SUBNET/g" $config
    title='IP CHANGED'
    body=$(cat << EOF
IP changed to: $IPADDR <br>
SUBNET changed to: $SUBNET <br>
DHCP $DHCP
EOF
)
else
    body='What are you trying to pull, mister?'
fi

cat << EOF
Content-type: text/html

<html><head><title>$title</title></head>
<body>$body</body></html>
EOF
```

Comment: I have changed permissions on the file to where anybody can edit  it but It still isnt working

Comment: If you copy the config file to `/tmp/net.config` and change the script I gave you to use `config=/tmp/net.config` then it should work.

Comment: Yes Its still not working, does apache need to have root permissions?

Comment: The thing is the script works in my command line but when I run it from the apache server it doesn't

Comment: Ok, most probably this is an SELinux setup issue. See my updated answer, I rewrote the first part.